# Why is "Auserkiesung" not an official word?

Tags: noun, nominalization

In the Duden there's that nice verb "auserkiesen". Why is there no "Auserkiesung" and what's the official noun for that verb?

Comment: The corresponding noun to "erkiesen" is "Kür".

Comment: The suffix -ung is one possibility of nominalization in German language, but this you can not apply as a generic rule.

Answer (score 9):

*Auserkiesen* (like *erkiesen* and *kiesen)* is one of the few [defective verbs](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb) of the German language: Only its participle forms *(auserkoren)* and rarely its preterite form *(erkor aus)* are in current use – the present forms are unknown even to most native speakers. This is also noted by the Duden in [its entry for *auserkiesen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auserkiesen)*:*

> im Infinitiv und im Präsens Aktiv ungebräuchlich

Historically this strong difference of present and past forms stems from the verb mingling with *küren* ([source](//www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kiesen_waehlen_ernennen)), which also provides for the verb’s default nominalisation: ***Kür**.*

Since there already is a short nice noun for this purpose and hardly anybody knows the presence stem anymore, there is no reason for another nominalisation like *Auserkiesung* to exist. Moreover, not even every common verb comes with a nominalisation on *-ung:*

> sehen, <s>Sehung</s>, Sichtung
>
> erleben, <s>Erlebung</s>, Erlebnis